# Is there any special field in political science to study security issues?

Tags: masters, united-kingdom, germany, political-science

In my country, students can follow a special field in political science which is about **security issues** (like Terrorist, Threats and  opportunities) in Masters programmes. The graduated people can work for Foreign ministry, intelligence services or embassies.

I know the fields in master can vary country by country, but is there any similar fields in German Universities?

What about UK?

If there is, can a non-citizen person study in these fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are several International Security Studies MA programmes in [Germany](https://www.google.de/search?q=master%20security%20political%20science&oq=master%20security%20political%20science&aqs=chrome..69i64j0j69i57.21485j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=master%20international%20security&tbs=ctr:countryDE&cr=countryDE) and [in the UK](https://www.google.de/search?q=master%20security%20political%20science&oq=master%20security%20political%20science&aqs=chrome..69i64j0j69i57.21485j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=master%20international%20security&tbs=ctr:countryUK&cr=countryUK). Examples from Germany include a [Master in Peace and Security Studies at the University Hamburg](https://www.uni-hamburg.de/campuscenter/studienangebot/studiengang.html?1115113334) and a [Master in International Security Studies at the Universität der Bundeswehr in Munich](https://www.unibw.de/casc/studiengaenge/MISS/M.A.%20International%20Security%20Studies).

In general, a EU citizen can study in other EU countries. Visa and admission criteria for non-EU citizens vary.